# HTML Div list with varying location (right or left or full)

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a list of objects that display in rows within a div.  When they are full width, they work fine.  As soon as I try to have the inner objects take up the left or right half of the parent, they cause all kinds of problems.  Below is how I want them to appear, and how they actually appear.  How do I achieve this layout with html/css?  I've tried floating elements (which tends to mess up the parent list) and inline-block with no luck.

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/bP0ZWFplDFc6755LNNb5?p=preview

HTML:

```
<div class="employee-container">
  <div class="full-shift">
    <p>Person 1 <span>(40)</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="employee-container">
  <div class="full-shift">
    <p>Person 2 <span>(40)</span> <span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span></p>   
  </div>
</div>
<div class="employee-container">
  <div class="first-half">
    <p>Person 3 <span>(40)</span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="second-half"></div>
</div>
<div class="employee-container">
  <div class="first-half"></div>
  <div class="second-half">
    <p>Person 4 <span>(44)</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.employee-container {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  margin-top: 6px;
}
.employee-container > div {
  padding: 3px;
  background-color: lightsteelblue;
}
.employee-container > div .full-shift {
  width: 100%;
}
.employee-container > div .first-half {
  width: 50%;
}
.employee-container > div .second-half {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Desired output:

[image: Div]

Actual output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML changes include removing the "second-half" div from Person(3) and the "first-half" div from Person(4).

```
<div class="employee-container">
  <div class="first-half">
    <p>Person 3 <span>(40)</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="employee-container">
  <div class="second-half">
    <p>Person 4 <span>(44)</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Float "first-half" left, and "second-half" right (Your original thought of 50% width was correct)

```
.first-half {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
.second-half {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}
```

Change box-sizing to border box for all elements (if you're curious about what this property does, Paul Irish has a great [blog post](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) on it)

```
html{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after{
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iamnottony/004s7ey9/)

Comment: Nice Tony. More elegant than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the child selectors from most of your styles. Note the class 'blank' added to the empty divs to remove the background colour. You must also leave no white space between the html for the first half and second half divs as inline-block takes white space into account.

```
 <div class="employee-container">
   <div class="full-shift">
     <p>Person 1 <span>(40)</span></p>
   </div>
 </div><div class="employee-container">
  <div class="full-shift">
    <p>Person 2 <span>(40)</span> <span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span></p>   
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="employee-container">
  <div class="first-half">
    <p>Person 3 <span>(40)</span></p>
  </div><div class="second-half blank"></div>
</div>
<div class="employee-container">
  <div class="first-half blank"></div><div class="second-half">
    <p>Person 4 <span>(44)</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.employee-container {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  margin-top: 6px;
}
.employee-container > div {
  padding: 3px;
  background-color: lightsteelblue;
}
.employee-container  div.full-shift {
  width: 100%;
}
.employee-container  div.first-half {

    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
}
.employee-container  div.second-half {

    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
}

.employee-container div.blank {
    background: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML:

```
<div class="employee-container">
    <div class="full-shift">
        <p>Person 1 <span>(40)</span></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="employee-container">
    <div class="full-shift">
        <p>Person 2 <span>(40)</span> <span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span>   </p>   
</div>
</div>
<div class="employee-container">
    <div class="first-half">
        <p>Person 3 <span>(40)</span></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="employee-container">
    <div class="second-half">
        <p>Person 4 <span>(44)</span></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.employee-container {
     margin-bottom: 6px;
     margin-top: 6px;
}
.employee-container > div {
    padding: 3px ;
    background-color: lightsteelblue;
}
.employee-container .full-shift {
    width: 100%;
}
.employee-container .first-half {
    width: 50%;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}
.employee-container .second-half {
   width: 50%;
   float:right;
}
```

Comment: A good answer would explain *why* the OP would want to do the things.