# Floating column within fixed row in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, css-float

My page contains a collection of elements, each element is a fixed height row.  Within the row, the content block should fill only part of the row.  This could be the entire row, only the left part, only the right part, or somewhere in the middle.

To draw this with html I was thinking of using two buffer divs (left and right side of the content).  Note how wide the buffers are will be set programmatically (with angular) so does not need to be set on the CSS.  This can just be hardcoded in the PLNKR with inline styles.

Here is my starting [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/bP0ZWFplDFc6755LNNb5?p=preview).

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39000536/html-div-list-with-varying-location-right-or-left-or-full), but was only needing 3 variations for rows (left half, right half, full width), now I need more flexibility.

```
<div class="employee-container">
   <div class="left-buffer"></div>
   <div class="content">
      <p>Show me full width</p>
   </div>
   <div class="right-buffer"></div>
</div>
<div class="employee-container">
   <div class="left-buffer"></div>
   <div class="content">
      <p>Show me floating left</p>
   </div>
   <div class="right-buffer"></div>
</div>
<div class="employee-container">
   <div class="left-buffer"></div>
   <div class="content">
      <p>Show me floating right</p>
   </div>
   <div class="right-buffer"></div>
</div>
<div class="employee-container">
   <div class="left-buffer"></div>
   <div class="content">
      <p>Show me in the middle</p>
   </div>
   <div class="right-buffer"></div>
</div>
```

The output will be similar to below, but in addition to having the option of floating the element to the right or left, it could float in the middle.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used `float`s to put it right / left and `margin:auto` to center the div using:

```
.left{
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
}
.right{
  float: right;
  width: 33.33%;
}
.center{
  margin: auto;
  width: 33.33%;
}
.right-buffer {
  clear:both;  
}
```

(Added some border / padding for illustration)

```css
/* Styles go here */

.employee-container {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  border: 1px solid lightsteelblue;
}
.employee-container > div.content {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: lightsteelblue;
}
.left{
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
}
.right{
  float: right;
  width: 33.33%;
}
.center{
  margin: auto;
  width: 33.33%;
}
.right-buffer {
  clear:both;  
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="employee-container">
          <div class="left-buffer"></div>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Show me full width</p>
          </div>
          <div class="right-buffer"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="employee-container">
          <div class="left-buffer"></div>
          <div class="content left">
            <p>Show me floating left</p>
          </div>
          <div class="right-buffer"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="employee-container">
          <div class="left-buffer"></div>
          <div class="content right">
            <p>Show me floating right</p>
          </div>
          <div class="right-buffer"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="employee-container">
          <div class="left-buffer"></div>
          <div class="content center">
            <p>Show me in the middle</p>
          </div>
          <div class="right-buffer"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Fantastic answer, this works great!  Not sure why my question is getting down votes.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood well your request. I've made it in Plunker with flexbox.

http://plnkr.co/edit/IxCupfRaXUWYlkVhsqga

```
 <style>
      .flex{display:flex;}
      .flex > *{flex:1;padding:2px}
 </style>

<body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="employee-container">
        <div class="left-buffer"></div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Show me full width</p>
      </div>
      <div class="right-buffer"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex">
    <div class="employee-container">
      <div class="left-buffer"></div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Show me floating left with a very big text nd it will adjust automatically</p>   
      </div>
      <div class="right-buffer"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="employee-container">
      <div class="left-buffer"></div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Show me floating right</p>
      </div>
      <div class="right-buffer"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="employee-container">
      <div class="left-buffer"></div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Show me in the middle small text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="right-buffer"></div>
    </div>        
    </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
```

Comment: This isn't right because the last 3 rows are merged together on the same row.   I need each row to remain on it's own space, but where the content displays on the row will vary.  I added a picture to the original question to attempt to illustrate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Code and plunker link may be it can help you -

Link [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/8sIEis7gl9o6GvJDIHYn?p=preview)

HTML Code

```
<body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="employee-container">
                            <div class="left-buffer"></div>
                            <div class="content">
                                <p>Show me full width</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="right-buffer"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="employee-container leftDiv">
                            <div class="left-buffer"></div>
                            <div class="content">
                                <p>Show me floating left</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="right-buffer"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="employee-container rightDiv">
                            <div class="left-buffer"></div>
                            <div class="content">
                                <p>Show me floating right</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="right-buffer"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 centeredDiv">
                        <div class="employee-container">
                            <div class="left-buffer"></div>
                            <div class="content">
                                <p>Show me in the middle</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="right-buffer"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS Code

```
.employee-container {
      margin-bottom: 6px;
      margin-top: 6px;
    }
    .employee-container > div {
      padding: 3px;
      background-color: lightsteelblue;
    }
    .centeredDiv{
      position:relative;
    }

    .centeredDiv > .employee-container{
      position:absolute;
      width:50%;
      left:25%;
    }

    .rightDiv{
      width:50%;
      float:right;
    }

    .leftDiv{
      width:50%;
      float:left;
    }
```